# JavaScript: Binding object to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, data-binding, bind

I'm returning an object that I'd love to be able to just loop over and bind it's contents to a DOM object by way of class or ID.

Is there a recommended way to do this without having to manually assign each element?

Best case scenarios is a function that will actually create an element with the data inside of it.

...otherwise I'm stuck manually creating and assigning all of the data, and there's a lot.

```
{
    "user_profile": {
        "user_meta_first_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_last_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_billing_first_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_billing_last_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_billing_address_1": "2589 asdasd Rd.",
        "user_meta_billing_address_2": "",
        "user_meta_billing_city": "asdsdasd",
        "user_meta_billing_postcode": "VVV 344",
        "user_meta_billing_country": "CA",
        "user_meta_billing_state": "AB",
        "user_meta_billing_email": "admin@thebandagency.ca",
        "user_meta_billing_phone": "2343423434",
        "user_meta_shipping_first_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_shipping_last_name": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_shipping_address_1": "2589 asdasd Rd.",
        "user_meta_shipping_address_2": "",
        "user_meta_shipping_city": "asdasd",
        "user_meta_shipping_postcode": "VVV 344",
        "user_meta_shipping_country": "CA",
        "user_meta_shipping_state": "AB",
        "user_meta_shipping_email": "",
        "user_meta_shipping_phone": "",
        "user_meta_paying_customer": "1"
    },
    "pet_profiles": {
        "2000": {
            "pet_name": "Wally the Wonder Pup",
            "pet_tag_serial": "V140000",
            "pet_tag_pin": "XGZSVEMZ",
            "pet_tag_expiry": "December 8, 2013",
            "pet_tag_active": "1",
            "pet_tag_size": "1",
            "pet_tag_design": "Basket Case"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you loop on your object with foreach function? Is it a JSON object?

Comment: Can we see just a little bit of code or example?

Comment: What's wrong with using `$(element).data('obj', myobj)` ?

Comment: Nothing Jack ... just want to make sure that I'm doing it the more recommended way. How would you suggest implementing it?

Comment: @dcolumbus Using `.data()` you can pretty much attach any object you want to a DOM node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your object is an array. You could use `each` JQuery function to loop through your object, then create an element with your object data inside of it.

```
$.each(map, function(key, value) { 
  $('#mainContainer').append('<div id="'+key+'">'+value+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just jsonData, and you want to display it all on the screen, you can use this recursive approach. I would suggest editing it, as it is pretty bare bones. http://pastebin.com/EzTZHJxW

```
(function () {
     var jsonData = dataSentFromServer();
     var detailsElement = document.getElementById("Details");
     function newDiv(txt) {
         var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
         if (txt != undefined)
             createDiv.innerHTML = txt;
         return createDiv;
     }

     var depth = 1;
     (function ComposeGraph(obj, el) {
         var ElementArray = [];
         var ChildArray = [];
         $.each(obj, function (name, value) {
             if (!$.isArray(value)) {

                 var appender = newDiv(name + " __:__ " + value);
                 appender.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:" + 10 * depth + "px;");
                 if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
                     appender.innerHTML = "<b>" + appender.innerHTML + "</b>";
                     depth++;
                     ComposeGraph(value, appender);
                     depth--;
                     ElementArray.push(el);
                     ChildArray.push(appender);
                 } else {
                     el.appendChild(appender);
                 }
             } else {
                 var appender = newDiv(name + " __:__ " + value);
                 appender.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:" + 10 * depth + "px;");
                 appender.innerHTML = "<b>" + appender.innerHTML + "</b>";
                 for (var i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
                     depth++;
                     ComposeGraph(value[i], appender);
                     depth--;
                 }
                 ElementArray.push(el);
                 ChildArray.push(appender);
             }
         });
         for (var i = 0, len = ElementArray.length; i < len; i++) {
             ElementArray[i].appendChild(ChildArray[i]);
         }
     })(jsonData, detailsElement);
 })();
```